# Maven Resources and docker-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I would like to understand better how Maven deals with resources and in particular how plugins can reuse the `Resources` infrastructure that Maven provides:

I have already read the resources section of [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) and looked at the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin).

Now I came across the [Docker Maven Plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) from Spotify. Which contains the following configuration section:

```
<configuration>
    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```

Looking at the [Readme](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md) of the plugin I could not find any explanation which child elements are allowed for a `<resource>` element. **I am assuming** that the `<resource>` element is in fact related to Maven's `org.apache.maven.model.Resource` class and that I can just reuse the documentation of Maven to understand who it works. But according to the Maven documentation I linked above, it seems that `<include>` elements must be nested inside an `<includes>` element which the above code listing does not do. Now I am confused.

To summarize: Where can I look to get a definitive answer if a plugin does not exactly document how its configuration works. Does there exist some kind of XML schema reference for plugins where I can lookup how particular elements work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to set configs like:

```
<dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
<dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
<dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
```

these one you can use for example by following:

fixes this by:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>yourImageName</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
                <dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Important are these two tags:

```
<dockerHost>https://192.168.99.100:2376</dockerHost>
<dockerCertPath>/Users/your_user/.docker/machine/machines/default</dockerCertPath>
```

I am using a dockerfile, which path you have to define with this tag:

```
<dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
```

Now you can build your jar and generate docker image via:

mvn package docker:build

Comment: I needed a way to copy the built `jar` artifect into the docker image without hard coding the version inside the `Dockerfile`. So in my `src/main/docker/Dockerfile` I wrote: `ADD backend-@project.version@.jar app.jar` and then used the Maven resources plugin to create a new `docker/Dockerfile` in `target`. This results for example in following line in the final Dockerfile: `ADD backend-0.5.5.jar app.jar`. I have set `<dockerDirectory>` to: `${project.build.directory}/docker`. Without that you would need to touch your docker file every time you bump the version number of your software.